# thread concurrently running and output variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, race-condition, critical-section

I ran into a Challenging on Trace this example:
Suppose we have two thread concurrently run these two `threads`. in the following code all threads access to shared variable `a, b, c`. the expected value for `c` after the running this code is: `4,7,6,13,-3,14,1.`

any help or idea who this output will be reached?

```
Initialization 
a=4;
b=0;
c=0;

Thread 1
if (a<b) then
    c=b-a;
else
    c=b+a;
endif

Thread 2
b=10;
c=-3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sequence for 1 (c = b + a implemented as c = b, c += a):

```
    (a<b) false  // thread 1 a == 4, b == 0
    else         // thread 1
    c = b + ...  // thread 1 c = b == 0
    b = 10       // thread 2
    c = -3       // thread 2 c = -3
    c = ... + a  // thread 1 c += a == 1
```

A sequence for 4

```
   (a<b) false   // thread 1 a == 4, b == 0
   a + b         // thread 1 sum of 4 + 0 = 4
   b = 10        // thread 2
   c = -3        // thread 2
   c = a + b     // thread 1  c = previously calculated sum of 4
```

A sequence for -3

```
   ...           // thread 1 runs first
   c = -3        // thread 2, last statement
```

A sequence for 13

```
   ...           // thread 1 is going to calculate c = a, c = b - c
   c = 4         // thread 1 c = a
   b = 10        // thread 2
   c = -3        // thread 2
   c = b - c     // thread 1 c = 10 - (-3) = 13
```

A sequence for 6

```
   b = 10        // thread 2
   c = -3        // thread 2
   (a<b) true    // thread 1
   c = b-a       // thread 1  c = 10 - 4 = 6
```

A sequence for 14

```
   (a<b) false   // thread 1
   b = 10        // thread 2
   c = -3        // thread 2
   c = b+a       // thread 1  c = 10 + 4 = 14
```

A sequence for 7 (c = b + a implemented as c = a, c += b):

```
   (a<b) true    // thread 1
   c = a         // thread 1  c = 4
   b = 10        // thread 2
   c = -3        // thread 2
   c += b        // thread 1  c = -3 + 10 = 7
```

Comment: Dear @rcgldr, I couldn't understand your answer !

Comment: The sequence occurs when the compiler implements thread1's c = b + a by doing c = b first, then doing c += a next, with thread2 changing b after thread1's c = b, and thread 2 changing c before thread1's c += a .

Comment: my question is who this value can be calculated: 4,7,6,13,-3,14,1?

Comment: In the original post, you mention you thought the 1 was wrong. I assumed you thought all the other cases were OK. Which other cases are you wondering about?

Comment: would you please inspect all case? I confused a lot. one month I search about it.

Comment: The 4 case isn't too difficult to explain. Try to figure out all the cases that you can figure out, and then return here to ask about the cases that you can't figure out.

Comment: At least see if you can figure out the case for 4, then update your original post and return here for the other cases.

Comment: you know you are so expert, but please consider me. I know waste your valuable times. but Infact I confused exactly. I didn't my TA until next week. If it's possible please learn me all cases. if it's not please say to accept you answer. I'm looking for your kindly answer. I think this site is a very useful  to learn new things...

Comment: I added a sequence for 4, please try to do one of the other cases and edit your original post, or you can post your own answer.

Comment: would you please add for -3 and 13? I accept it. thanks anyway

Comment: is  it  possible to complete your answer?

Comment: I inspect this question more times, I think 14 and 6 is not occurred with this two threads !, and @MaryamGhizhi is Wrong...

Comment: @user4249446 - 14 == 10 + 4, 6 == 10 - 4, look at the sequences again to see this.

Comment: I'm so glad that hear from you, i get stuck on it :), would you please add the sequence? @rcgldr.

Comment: @rcgldr, it's a good answer, but what about "7" ? output, please add the sequence....

Comment: why for 13, you say (this seems unlikely)?

Comment: @MaryamGhizhi - because it's extra code. load a, store c, load b, subtract c, store c, instead of load b, subtract a, store c.